# Replacing values and recalculating in reactive tables

Tags: r, shiny

I have a table with three columns: Sales,Prices and Revenue. I want to create an app which will ask for user input regarding prices but when no input has been i.e before the action button is pressed the chart will calculate the revenue in terms of some base prices already in the code. I am unable to generate this reactive. I have provided the code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "A", label = "A",value=0),
      numericInput(inputId = "B", label = "B",value=0),
      numericInput(inputId = "C", label = "C",value=0),
      numericInput(inputId = "D", label = "D",value=0),
      actionButton("action","Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("mytable")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(data.table)
library(googleVis)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  Sales<-c(2,6,9,10)
  Prices<-c(34,43,76,89)
  Prices_user<-reactive({
    c(input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D)
  })
  Rev<-Sales*Prices
  Rev_user<-reactive({
    Sales*Prices_user()
  })

  combined<-data.frame(Sales,Prices,Rev)
  combined_user<-reactive({
    data.frame(Sales,Prices_user(),Rev_user())
  })
  output$mytable<-renderGvis({  
    if(input$action ==0){
      gvisTable(combined)
      }else{
        gvisTable(combined_user())
      }

  })  
})
```

Comment: You need to have a line that says ```output$mytable <- renderGvis [etc.]``` in your server.R. Otherwise, your line ```htmlOutput("mytable")``` in ui.R doesn't point to anything.

Comment: I have made the edit. But even though the table is generated its taking the default prices i.e. 0

Comment: Instead of ```Prices<-c(34,43,76,89)``` (exclude it), I think you can set the default values of A, B, C, and D as 34, 43, 76, and 89. For example, ```numericInput(inputId = "A", label = "A",value=34),```

Comment: Yes. I had considered that method but that in turn shows user input as default values in the beginning. What I wanted was this action be performed from pre fixed prices in server while default input shows 0 implying it has to be changed. Simply put I wanted to make the Prices vector a variable which becomes the reactive vector when submit is pressed.

Comment: I see. You could make two separate tables with an ```ifelse()``` statement. It would go: ```output$mytable <- ifelse(input$action, [code for table with inputs], [code for default table])```

Comment: I have modified my server.R in the code provided keeping ui same but the output is not rendered.

Comment: Ah, ```actionButton``` gives 0 as a default, then counts up by 1 each time it is pressed (not like checkboxInput, which is TRUE or FALSE). Try ```output$mytable <- ifelse(input$action != 0, [...])``` This is my last attempt, then I'm going to bed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your server.R like this (untested):

```
library(data.table)
library(googleVis)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$mytable <- ifelse(input$action != 0,

    Sales<-c(2,6,9,10)
    Prices <-reactive({
      c(input$A,input$B,input$C,input$D)
    })
    Rev<-reactive({
      Sales*Prices()
    })
    combined<-data.frame(Sales,Prices,Rev)
    renderGvis({
      gvisTable(combined)
    }),

    Sales<-c(2,6,9,10)
    Prices<-c(34,43,76,89)
    Rev<-reactive({
      Sales*Prices()
    })
    combined<-data.frame(Sales,Prices,Rev)
    renderGvis({
      gvisTable(combined)
    })

  ) 
})
```

Comment: Yes this works.I also tried another way which I have put in my code. That works too. Thank you for your patience and help.